# How much space is SMS taking up?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, sms

When I plug my iPhone into the PC and iTunes comes up, the "Other" is taking up about 40% of the bar.  I suspect most of it is SMS/iMessage, since I am a heavy user (with photos and sometimes videos).

Questions:

1. How do I actually see how much space SMS is taking up?
2. Is there a way to delete everything prior to a certain date?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can see how much storage your Messages are taking up directly on your iOS device by going to: **Settings > General > Usage**
2. No, you cannot mass delete from a specific period of time.

If you are sending lots of images and videos, that 40% probably *is* your Messages database which includes pictures and videos.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to figure things out directly, but I use [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to both archive all calls, all SMS and all voicemail.

From there you can see how large it is on the Mac and work out if iTunes is classifying the SMS media as other or as Photos and Videos.

I've never actually tried to clear a partial amount of SMS and instead just wipe the device every once in a while and set things up newly. Perhaps an editor or another answer can field that portion of your question.

Answer (score -1):

The 40% of the bar is usually made of the iphone's own operating system. If you update to new operating frequently a lot of space would be taken especially if yours is only 16gb.

You cannot actually check how much space SMS are taking, but they only take a very small percentage.

You also cannot remove *only some* of the SMSs if not manually. If yours is jailbroken, a new tweak could be made in the future.